# Subfolder Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have two folders in the GameGold folder that I want to have individual controllers for.

The folders are "coins" and "pgo". I have looked into routing a little but they only really show you how to route to a folder or subfolder but nothing deeper.

I also want to make it possible to go to an index in the GoldGold folder too. I am kind of new to ASP.Net and MVC but not C#, I just can't completely wrap my head around the routing configuration.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "GameGold",
    url: "Products/GameGold/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Coins", action = "Index" }
);
```

Url examples:

```
website.com/Products/GameGold/Coins/Index

website.com/Products/GameGold/Pgo/Index

website.com/Products/GameGold/Index
```

I'd like to also include the dashs as they help with SEO.

EDIT:

I have tried this method below.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "GameGold",
        url: "Products/GameGold/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Coins", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

And now I just get this??? Why is it looking inside the views rather than the folders I have written in the code!!

```
The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Coins/Index.aspx
~/Views/Coins/Index.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
~/Views/Coins/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Coins/Index.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml
```

Comment: Sounds like a MVC confusion, you cant have controllers for views, its the other way around, Controllers -> ActionResults use views... Perhaps if you explain what the two different url might look like we can help you further

Comment: @pmeyer added some examples

Comment: Would there be a GameGoldController, CoinsController, PgoController? If so, could you not have 3 MapRoute entries for the URL examples above, specifying the respective controller (e.g. `controller = "Pgo"` and `controller = "Coins"`)? Or am I missing something?

Comment: You can please all three methods under the same controller, each with its own view and once you have all of that working under the normal MVC archicture you can work on creating custom routes for it. You can have a Game controller with the following ActionResults Coint, Pgo, Index and each with its own view.

Comment: @pmeyer There will be more content than the index's it would be messy for me.

Comment: @BryanWoodford Yes there would be a controller for GameGold, Coins and Pgo.

Comment: What is the url that generates the above error?

Comment: @ekad Coins, I am only testing coins until I can get something to appear but nothing will so far.

Comment: You said you have CoinsController, so I think the route configuration should be `defaults: new { controller = "Coins", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }`.

Comment: @ekad Sorry i did that I didn't mean to copy the one I did. The way you mention is the way I have it.

Comment: @Aidan - did you manage to resolve it?